# ListView dont render new item after state update

Tags: listview, reactjs, react-native, render, redux

I have a React-Native project with Redux.

I have the component "Comments" embeded in component "ParentComponent".

After add comment my "Comments" component receive the updated state and call Render function with new array in props. But dont draw the new cells on listView.

My ActionComments Code

addComment:

```
if(parent_id){
  commentsList[parent_index].responses.push(responseObject)
}else{
  commentsList.splice(0, 0, responseObject)
}
Actions.pop()

var newList = commentsList
dispatch(commentsListUpdate(newList))
```

CommentListUpdate:

```
function commentsListUpdate(list) {
  return {
    type: types.COMMENTS_LIST_UPDATE,
    list
  };
}
```

My Reducer:

```
case types.COMMENTS_LIST_UPDATE:
  return {
    ...state,
    isFetching: false,
    list: action.list
  };
```

My Component:

```
class Comments extends Component {
  render(){
    let ds = new ListView.DataSource({
        rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2
    });
    let dataSource = ds.cloneWithRows(this.props.list);

    return (
        <ListView
         dataSource={dataSource}
         renderRow={this._renderRow.bind(this)}
        />
    )
  }

  _renderRow(rowData: string, sectionID: number, rowID: number) {
        return (
            <View style={Styles.viewStyle}>
                <Comment
                    name={rowData.user.full_name}
                    avatar={rowData.user.photo_dir}
                    comment={rowData.content}
                    list={rowData.responses}
                    dispatch={this.props.dispatch}
                    owner_id={this.props.owner_id}
                />
            </View>
        )
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you share bits of your code? Especially the part where you update the datasource.

Answer (score 0):

Can you show us your reducer? I think you have muted the state by pushing the new element like this:

```
case 'ADD_ITEM':
    return state.push(item)
```

If you mutate the state redux will not see the difference between OLD state and NEW state. Instead, you MUST return a new array:

```
case 'ADD_ITEM':
    return [...state, item]
```

**edit** ([compiled code](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?evaluate=true&lineWrap=false&presets=es2015%2Creact%2Cstage-2&code=const%20oldState%20%3D%20%5B1%2C2%2C3%5D%0Aconst%20newState%20%3D%20%5B...oldState%2C%204%5D))

```
case 'ADD_ITEM':
    return [].concat(state, [item])
```

Comment: How can apply that to my code? My state have list insaid.
 `const initialState = {
  list:[],
  isFetching: false,
};`

Comment: I try:
    `case types.COMMENTS_LIST_UPDATE:
      return {
        ...state,
        isFetching: false,
        list: [].concat(action.list)
      };`

I think it isnt the problem because my component call render function and have the list in state with the new item, but dont draw the new element list.

Comment: Yes it looks good on your reducer part. Can you show me more about your render part?

Comment: Sure, i add it on main post

Comment: Did you try to first remove the dataSource check diff?

Comment: How can i remove it?